# Use read.table and rename column names

Tags: r

I am new to r and am using the read.table command to import a text file.  My column names are PatID, AgePat, SexPat and WeightPat.  I want to change these to simply PatID (no change), Age, Sex and Weight.  How do I do this?  Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways to do what you want:

```
colnames(data) [2:4] <- c("Age","Sex","Income")
```

or

```
colnames(x)[2:4] <- sub("Pat","",colnames(x)[2:4])
```

If you're new to R, I would recommend the ebook "R Fundamentals & Graphics" which will give you a solid grasp of R basics. Better than fumbling around and wasting your time.

Answer (score 13):

`read.table` has a `col.names` argument

```
read.table("/path/to/file", header=TRUE, col.names=c("PatID", "Age", "Sex", "Weight"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Say the `DataFrame` name is `Data`. Just do:

```
names(Data) <- c("PatID", "Age", "Sex", "Weight")
```